# Add attributes to a control class

Tags: c#, asp.net

I wanna know if it is possible to add attribute to a `Control` in c#.

I have a method it receive an object in parameter :

```
    public void CreateTooltip(Object controltoadd = null)
    {
        var myDiv = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
        myDiv.Attributes.Add("width", "100%");

        myDiv.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "ShowHint('" + this.GetType() + "','test');");
        myDiv.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "HideHint();");

        if (controltoadd == null)
        {
            List<Control> listcc = new List<Control>();

            for (int i = 0; i < this.Controls.Count; i++)
            {
                Control cc = this.Controls[i];
                string test = cc.GetType().ToString();
                listcc.Add(cc);
            }

            this.Controls.Clear();

            for (int i = 0; i < listcc.Count; i++)
            {
                Control cc = listcc[i];
                myDiv.Controls.Add(cc);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Control cc = (Control)controltoadd;

            //Don't know what to do here...
        }

        this.Controls.Add(myDiv);
    }
```

If the object is null, I create a `HtmlGenericControl("div")` and then I add the `Attributes` I want. But the problem is when the Object is not null, I convert it to `Control`, and the property `Attributes` is not available. I use control because I never know which is the type of the object I received in the parameter.

Comment: You need to cast it as a `WebControl` or a `HtmlGenericControl` I believe. `Control` does not contain the property `Attributes`. You can test what the object you pass is by using `is`.

Comment: Moved to an answer! :)

Comment: You could make it a generic method with a constraint to [`IAttributeAccessor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.iattributeaccessor.aspx). Both, `HtmlControl` and `WebControl` implement that interface to get/set attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast it as a `WebControl` or a `HtmlGenericControl` I believe. `Control` does not contain the property `Attributes`. You can test what the object you pass is by using `is`.

```
if (control is WebControl)
{
    var webControl = (WebControl)control;
}
```

Or if you prefer to use `as`:

```
var webControl = control as WebControl;

if (webcontrol != null)
{
    // code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So if it's actually a `WebControl` (child-class of `Control`) then you can cast it to it and use it's [`Attributes` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.attributes.aspx). `Control` itself has no property `Attributes` as you've already noticed:

```
WebControl wc = controltoadd as WebControl;
if(wc != null)
{
    // wc.Attributes.Add...
}
```

If it's a `HtmlControl` cast it to that:

```
else
{
    HtmlControl hc = controltoadd as HtmlControl;
    if(hc != null)
    {
        // hc.Attributes.Add...
    }
}
```

Another option would be to make it a generic method that accepts only controls that implement [`IAttributeAccessor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.iattributeaccessor.aspx). Both, `HtmlControl` and `WebControl` implement that interface to get/set attributes.:

```
public void CreateTooltip<T>(T controlToAdd)where T: IAttributeAccessor, Control
{
    // ....
    controlToAdd.SetAttribute("width", "100%");
}
```